# Damaged Indian passport

Tags: passports

My family and I are travelling to Bali, Indonesia from Bangalore, for holidays. Our air tickets are booked for Monday, April 2. The problem is last night my daughter passport's cover was damaged. She is just 5 years old. Can anyone help me out with this problem.

[image]

Comment: The degree of damage will matter here. Can you post a photo without showing any personal information?

Comment: Is it just the booklet cover page? Is the ID page damaged?

Comment: Booklet cover page

Comment: I highly doubt you will get through Indian immigration. Is the bio page intact?

Comment: Bio page i.e personal information pages rest all are safe only front cover part and backside of front cover is damaged as image is uploaded

Comment: you have to get new one

Comment: @SundeepKumar What did you end up doing? If you got a re-issued passport, did you have to get the visa stamped also?

Answer (score 3):

India classes [passport damage into two classes](http://www.passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/online/faqLostDamagedPassports): damaged, and damaged beyond recognition (which means that your personal information page is damaged or unreadable).

Because this is only "damaged" you can get expedited service to have it replaced. The [linked FAQ](http://www.passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/online/faqLostDamagedPassports) covers this situation:

> In case your passport has not been damaged beyond recognition, i.e. passport number is legible, name is legible and photo is intact, then you can apply for re-issue of passport under the Tatkaal scheme. But, if passport has been damaged beyond recognition, then you cannot apply under the Tatkaal scheme. In that case, you need to visit Passport Officer at your nearest Passport Seva Kendra to get the passport on urgent basis.

The [Tatkaal scheme](http://passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/online/faqTatkaalPassports) can usually replace your passport within 1-3 working days.

Comment: April 2 is a Monday. There is NO WAY that her passport will be replaced in time for their trip. The OP wants to know whether or not she'll be allowed to travel with the passport in the state it is. The new Indian passports have the bio page which is not attached to the cover. It's a separate page. If that's the case, they might, just might be able to go. Also, Indian passports are one of the worst when it comes to quality.

Comment: It's very unlikely they'll be able to go. And this answer is written not only for them but for everyone else who will come after them.